# Curl: POSTs converting to GETs

Tags: php, post, curl, header, get

I am designing a simple twitter login script with CURL and when I try to execute it, the login form is sent as GET when I am sending it as POST. Due to this only the header of the user's homepage is displayed in the browser.

Any input is appreciated.

```
<?php

function tw_connect($user, $pwd) {

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16";
$ch = curl_init('http://www.twitter.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$c = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match_all('#authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="(.*)"#U', $c, $g);
$g = $g[1][0];

$post = 'authenticity_token=' . trim($g[1]) . '&authenticity_token=' . trim($g[1]) .
    '&return_to_ssl=false&redirect_after_login=&session' . urlencode("[username_or_email]") . 
    '=' . $user . '&'  . urlencode("session[password]") . '=' . $pwd . '&commit=' . urlencode("Sign In");
$ch2 = curl_init('https://twitter.com/sessions');

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://twitter.com/');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$v = curl_exec($ch2);

echo $v;

}

tw_connect('username','password');

?>
```

Comment: What does make you think that your script send data as GET not POST?

Comment: I checked it with both fiddler and LiveHTTPHeader addon for firefox. Both shows it as a GET request.

Comment: Try to remove TRUE and replace it with 1.

Comment: I get this error 'Undefined offset: 1 in C:\file\address.php on line 15' when I replace TRUE with 1

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this:

```
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

When redirecting through a `Location` header, the POST will be dropped and the request will be turned into a GET. I'm not sure if it's really necessary here or not.

Comment: Just checked and the same thing again after the removal of the above line.

Comment: @Dew: I know for sure that this is a cause of the issue you describe (tested it here). However, it seems it is not the only one, but I can't reproduce the problem except when using FOLLOWLOCATION... :(